# FailedToperformActionOnBlockedControlException when try to use Visual Studio UI tester

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, ribbon

I'm trying to put in place some UI tests with Visual Studio for my UI project in c# with WPF.

So I created a Test project and I started to create Coded UI tests as said in the tutoriel of Microsoft : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286681%28v=vs.100%29.aspx.

But when i launch the tests, i have the following exception :

```
MyProjectTestsUnitaires.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1 test method threw an exception:
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.FailedToPerformActionOnBlockedControlException: Control is blocked by another control. Make the blocked control visible and retry.
```

This append when i click on one of a button of the Windows Ribbon. More precisely, when i study the code generated for this test,  here what i have :

```
WpfTabList uIRibbonTabList = this.UIProjectWindow.UIRubbanCustom.UIRibbonTabList;
            WpfTabPage uIONGLET2TabPage = this.UIProjectWindow.UIRubbanCustom.UIRibbonTabList.UIONGLET2TabPage;
            WinListItem uIImagesjpgListItem = this.UIOuvrirWindow.UIItemWindow.UIVuedélémentsList.UIImagesjpgListItem;
            #endregion

        ApplicationUnderTest MyProjectApplication = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(this.RecordedMethod1Params.ExePath, this.RecordedMethod1Params.AlternateExePath);

        // Clic 'Ribbon' liste d'onglets
        Mouse.Click(uIRibbonTabList, new Point(0, 82));

        // Clic 'ONGLET2' onglet
        Mouse.Click(uIONGLET2TabPage, new Point(-152, 58));

        // Clic 'ONGLET2' onglet
        Mouse.Click(uIONGLET2TabPage, new Point(-129, 53));

        // Double-clic 'images.jpg' élément de liste
        Mouse.DoubleClick(uIImagesjpgListItem, new Point(25, 60));
```

I see with this code that the clicks are performed on the ONGLET2 of the ribbon which is the second header, whereas it is not visible on the screen. The clicks would have been registered on the ONGLET1 which is the first header.

How can we use the UI tests with the windows ribbon ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, and unfortunately I don't know how to answer it, but if you got here by googling "FailedToperformActionOnBlockedControlException" I might be able to help... the issue here is some other control is blocking the control you're trying to act on. The first step to debugging this kind of thing is to determine which control is blocking the control you want. Regardless of whether you're recording or hand-coding (switch to hand coding if you're not already-- trust me it will save you time in the long run), use the CodedUi Test Builder to get the properties on the blocking control. In VS 2015, put your cursor in a test method then select Test > Generate Code for CodedUI Test > Use CodedUI Test Builder. Once your control is visible, click and drag the gray "Target" icon until you see a rectangle around the object you want to select. Let go, and you will have the metadata on the blocking control. From there, you may decide to use that control (if you're clicking), use that control to get a relative point, or find another creative solution. Hope that helps!